# How do I mock local variable for a function in a service? Jasmine/Karma tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

An Angular service has several functions. All of them make use of a local variable defined via a `var varName` at the top of the file.

Is there any way of mocking this variable when unit-testing the function?

Comment: i appreciate this was asked a while ago now, but quick suggestion: if you were to put a code example here, someone may provide you with a more in-depth answer, with multiple options for your situation

Comment: A bit late but still, @adarren - i too facing same challenge as Nikolay Melnikov. My question link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921670/is-it-possible-to-mock-local-variable-in-angularjs-factory-from-karma. Any help would be much appreciated. I know this question has already an accepted answer. But still i am looking for some great answer as it is more than 1 year ahead now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short no.

The simplest way would be to put it on $scope level. Or Maybe as an angularjs constant

[angular constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)

Or if you'r a really crazy dude you can make a script that change the value of the var, but seriously don't do that, it's crazy.